# Developer mode in Dawn of War: Dark Crusade

Tags: keyboard, warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war

Here how you're meant to do it:

1. Right click on the shortcut
2. Append the path with `-dev`
3. Once in the game, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> to launch the console.

Here shortcut properties:

[image: shorcut properties]

I launch the game via the shortcut, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> and nothing happens. Maybe it's a problem with my keyboard? My tilde key is to the left of enter and above the <kbd>shift</kbd>. It's actually a <kbd>#</kbd> and a <kbd>~</kbd>. You get the <kbd>~</kbd> by holding down <kbd>shift</kbd>.

Comment: Might be something to do with the UK keyboard- the tilde key on a US keyboard is next to the 1.

Comment: @Starkers - Were you able to solve your problem? If Lucas' answer helps, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark under the vote count :)

Answer (score 1):

It probably is not tilde (~) for you. The tilde on American keyboards is located on the very upper-left corner of the main body of keys (just below the function keys). Try hitting the key above your TAB key, in the left corner, while holding `CTRL` and `SHIFT` together. This is the standard "console key" for many games, so keep that one in mind.

I'm honestly not sure why they usually refer to it by the tilde either; on American keyboards, you get a grave character (`) when the key is pressed, and tilde when you hit SHIFT. That would be like saying "Press !" when you really want the user to press "1" on the num row. Ah, well.